# How can I play God of War: Ascension local multiplayer?

Tags: god-of-war-ascension

How do I play God of War Ascension with 2 controllers? I know how to play online, but can 2 people play on the same console?

Comment: nice [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-can-i-play-god-of-war-ascension-local-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-can-i-play-god-of-war-ascension-local-multiplayer)

Answer (score 3):

For an official answer, if you look at the back of any video game, it will tell you how many players the game is, and if it is multiplayer. On the game case, it says 1 player locally, and 2-8 network players.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](http://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130412010802AANKHnl), it does not have offline multiplayer, which means almost surely that you cannot do multiplayer on a single console.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't find an official source on this, I've found multiple forum posts, discussions, etc that claim there is no local multiplayer. Apparently the developers have been listening to the community and fixing issues (what a refreshing change that must be!) so it's possible they may add the feature further down the line. I wouldn't hold my breath, though.

Sources:

- [GameFaqs forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/667703-god-of-war-ascension/64905372)
- [Yahoo! Answers](http://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130412010802AANKHnl)
- [Playstation Community](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/God-of-War-Ascension-Multiplayer/Any-news-on-offline-local-multiplayer/td-p/39136621)

On the other hand, I've also found references to the game *having* local multiplayer at 
[Den of Geek](http://www.denofgeek.com/games/12500/god-of-war-ascension-multiplayer-details), but this was a preview so the information is most likely simply outdated.